# Macでcabocha-pythonが使えない

Tags: macos, cabocha

日本語が苦手で用語が曖昧かもしれません。お許しください。

[MeCabとCaboChaをMacに導入してPythonから使ってみる](https://qiita.com/musaprg/items/9a572ad5c4e28f79d2ae)

上記ページに参考してcabocha-pythonをMacで使いたいんです。コマンドラインでCabochaが使えますが、以下のコマンドでインストールしたPythonバインディングでPythonから使えないです。

以下のコマンドでcabocha-pythonをインストールできました。

```bash
% curl -OL https://github.com/taku910/cabocha/archive/master.zip
% unzip master.zip
% cd cabocha-master
% pip install python/
```

```bash
Processing ./python
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cabocha-python
  Building wheel for cabocha-python (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for cabocha-python: filename=cabocha_python-0.69-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl size=24383 sha256=a9c5035bf5d53158daf77308a32ed7fe15f4fab17f551cbc3807ba0a19bb62d1
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/26/9wdtrsyd4mxcx7wh7m398khc0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-268kjen1/wheels/e6/a3/17/93356be0304ed4b17e7d14180b217eacbd9c7075cb4065f167
Successfully built cabocha-python
Installing collected packages: cabocha-python
Successfully installed cabocha-python-0.69
```

でも、実際に使ってみると、エラーが出てきました。

```bash
/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/bin/python3.10 /Users/hurui05/Desktop/mecab/frontend/src/cleaners/pseudo_cleaner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hurui05/Desktop/mecab/frontend/src/cleaners/pseudo_cleaner.py", line 781, in <module>
    run_cabocha_demo()
  File "/Users/hurui05/Desktop/mecab/frontend/src/cleaners/pseudo_cleaner.py", line 749, in run_cabocha_demo
    import CaboCha
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CaboCha.py", line 28, in <module>
    _CaboCha = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CaboCha.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_CaboCha', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_CaboCha.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN7CaboCha12createParserEPKc'
```

以下のページで似たような問題が記述されていましたが、解決方法は私の場合には役に立たないみたいです。

[macでmecab-python3のimport error(Symbol not found)を解決](https://qiita.com/G1998G/items/2ad1b62c0285e478bfab)

```bash
% otool -L /Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_CaboCha.cpython-310-darwin.so

/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_CaboCha.cpython-310-darwin.so:
        /usr/local/lib/libcrfpp.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        @rpath/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.1.0)
        @rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.100.3)
```

```bash
% ls /opt/homebrew/lib

libcrfpp.0.dylib        libcrfpp.dylib          libgmp.a                libgmpxx.4.dylib        libgmpxx.dylib
libcrfpp.a              libgmp.10.dylib         libgmp.dylib            libgmpxx.a              pkgconfig
```

`install_tool_name -change`を使ってみると、

```bash
% install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/lib/libcrfpp.0.dylib" /opt/homebrew/lib/libcrfpp.0.dylib /Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_CaboCha.cpython-310-darwin.so

% otool -L /Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_CaboCha.cpython-310-darwin.so

/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_CaboCha.cpython-310-darwin.so:
        /opt/homebrew/lib/libcrfpp.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        @rpath/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.1.0)
        @rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.100.3)
```

結局同じエラーが出てきました。

```bash
/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/bin/python3.10 /Users/hurui05/Desktop/mecab/frontend/src/cleaners/pseudo_cleaner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hurui05/Desktop/mecab/frontend/src/cleaners/pseudo_cleaner.py", line 781, in <module>
    run_cabocha_demo()
  File "/Users/hurui05/Desktop/mecab/frontend/src/cleaners/pseudo_cleaner.py", line 749, in run_cabocha_demo
    import CaboCha
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CaboCha.py", line 28, in <module>
    _CaboCha = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CaboCha.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_CaboCha', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/hurui05/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_CaboCha.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN7CaboCha12createParserEPKc'
```

助けてください！

Comment: > 以下のコマンドでcabocha-pythonをインストールできました。

違います。それはcabocha-pythonではありません。

https://github.com/kenkov/cabocha/blob/0.1.4/cabocha/analyzer.py#L4

 を見ると中でCaboChaバインディングを呼んで何かをするユーティリティです。

Comment: CaboChaバインディングのインストールはその一つ上です。調査するならそこのログが必要かと思います。あと、その時点で動作確認しているはずですがそこは上手く実行できたのですか?

Comment: コメントいありがとうございます！インストール方法を変えてやり直しました。エラーが以前とはちょっ違うんですが、結果だけ見れば同じことみたいです。

Comment: 一応コメントだけ残しておきます。Apple Siliconバイナリ環境になってから「以下のコマンドでcabocha-pythonをインストールできました。」の部分でやっているコマンドが**私には成功できてない**ので、どういう環境だとこれが成功するのかなと感じています。qiitaの記事もApple Siliconバイナリ環境の話ではないので、書かれてない何かをやってビルドが通るようにしたのかなとも思いました。回答できることはないのですが悪しからず。